# How to compose excel formula to remove green warning

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my formula

```
=IF(COUNT(DY11:DZ11),AVERAGE(DY11:DZ11),"")
```

for which a green triangle warning is coming.

Warning message is

> The formula in this cell refers to a range that has additional numbers adjacent to it.

I have seen this link

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/error-the-formula-in-this-cell-refers-to-a-range/c04fc9b1-2994-4343-b23d-9591dcf7f8b6

but I still could not compose the above formula in such a way to get rid of warning.

Can someone suggest a good fix for formula?

Comment: This is probably a bad idea, bit if it's a purely visual thing, you could move the formula to a different sheet and then refer to the calculated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all the cells references from relative to absolute.

```
=IF(COUNT($DY$11:$DZ$11),AVERAGE($DY$11:$DZ$11),"")
```

I'm not sure why this works - I guess because a relative reference is meant for sliding and spilling.